# Hardware id and class of driver inf file

Tags: windows, driver

I have a Honeywell Voyager MS 9540 laser scanner.
I want to use winusb from Microsoft (Windows xp) in order to send ascii codes to the scanner device.
The winusb driver installation needs an inf file.
I have 2 questions concering this inf file:

First question about the hardware id (hw-id).
The documentation says about the INF models section:

```
device-description=install-section-name[,hw-id][,compatible-id...]
```

And in a sample inf file this line is:

```
%DeviceName% =USB_Install, USB\VID_0547&PID_1002
```

Here, the string after the comma is the hardware id.
I looked in the laser scanner manuals, but did not find any hardware id in it.
Is it possible that all laser scanners have the same hardware id or is this a vendor specific id?
I opened the device manager, selected an usb entry and looked in the details section. 
There was a hardware ids section with strings similar to the sample (USB\Vid_0bda&Pid_0111&Rev_110=). But how can I know which usb entry is my usb laser scanner?

Second question:
The honeywell laser scanner scans a barcode. When you have notepad open, it prints the digits of the barcode as text into notepad as if it was entered with the keyboard.
In the version section of the INF file you have to define a class and a classguid.
Should i select for this usb laser scanner "Class = USB" or "Class = HIDClass" (Human Interface Devices, because it is also a hid)?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the hardware id in the device manager. When you open the property window of a device, the third tab called details, contains a selector, which shows you the hardware id assigned to the device itself.

The class field in the inf file contains the category under which the device is installed. I do not know, if this changes the driver behavior itself.